# React Error: Cannot find module './common'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I've scoured the internet for an answer to this, and haven't found anything yet that works. I'm new to using React, but my friend asked for help with some CSS so I cloned his React project from github (the React app is successfully online and he can work on it locally). Repo is here: https://github.com/brandonkun5/TrueAlpha

When I ran npm start, it told me I had no module 'react-scripts', so I ran `npm install react-scripts`

Now, when I run npm start, I get the following message:
`internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638`
`throw err;`

`Error: Cannot find module './common'`

So far, I've tried:

- `npm del package.json`
- `npm del node_modules`
- `npm install`
- Moving the folder into a different location
- Searching the code for 'Require ('common')" and 'Require ('./common')
- Updating to the last node version

and nothing has worked yet. Any ideas on what could be causing this error?

Comment: can you link the repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file common.js is missing in node_modules/debug/src/common.js. I copied it from another React project of mine and run npm start in the console and then it worked. Try to copy that file from the path above to same path in this project and it should work. Second option is to run "npm install debug" and file will installed and debug folder will be updated.

Comment: That looks like the problem! Where can I find a common.js file to copy? I've googled and haven't found anything. And I don't think adding a blank common.js would help, right?

Comment: No it won't help, Run in the console "npm install debug" and then it will update the dubug folder and install missing files. @PntButterWolf